# C++ no match for 'operator='

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I'm currently working on an assignement concerning mobile robots. I'm developing on Windows with QT-Creator, using CMake and Visual C++ Compiler 10.0.

As the robot's working on Ubuntu, I need to compile the projekt using QT-Creator on Ubuntu with the GNU x86 compiler.

Now here's the problem, concerning the class `Box`, which is just storing some int-values:

**Box.h**

```
public:
Box();                                                                  
Box(int name, int sX, int sY, int width, int heigth);               
Box& operator = (Box &src);                                             
bool operator == (Box &src);                                     

private:
int name;                                                              
int startX, startY, endX, endY;                                       
int cgx, cgy;                                                        
int width, height;
```

There are also some get-methods in this header (like int getName() ).

The overloaded assignment-operator looks as following:

```
Box &Box::operator =(Box &src){
    this->cgx = src.getCenterX();
    this->cgy = src.getCenterY();
    this->endX = src.getEndX();
    this->endY = src.getEndY();
    this->startX = src.getStartX();
    this->startY = src.getStartY();

   return *this;}
```

I'm using Box objects in another class, stored in a `std::list<Box>`.

On Windows, everything works fine. But on Ubuntu I get the error-message `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Box' and 'const Box')` , which occurs in a function of `std::list`.

I'm quite new to C++ and haven't used `const` explicit anywhere. So how does this error happen and how do I solve it?

Comment: `Box& operator = (const Box &src);`

Comment: in addition to the other comments, `bool operator == (const Box &src) const`; for `==` as well (`const &` parameter and mark the method as `const`).

Comment: ... and then marking all of the `get...` methods const, as well, so they can be called on `src`. These are generally good practices, anyway, not just solutions to this specific problem.

Comment: @sharptooth completely different set of operators, this is the assignment operator. Not the equality compare.

Comment: I would suggest a reading of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: I would say operator = not copying the name is counter-intuitive.

Comment: You are very likely using the assignment operator with an rvalue which can only bind to `const` lvalue reference in C++98.

Comment: @Mgetz: Yeap. That was a typo. I was talking about implementing `operator!=()` by reusing `operator==()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manually implement the assignment `operator=()` for your `Box` class (note that the compiler will implement a *default* *member-wise assignment* `operator=` if you don't provide one), consider following a pattern something like this:

1. use `const Box&` (not just `Box&`) as the input source type, since you are not modifying the source;
2. check for self-assignment inside the overloaded operator implementation (`if (&src != this)...`).

In code:

```
Box& Box::operator=(const Box& src) 
{
    if (&src != this) 
    {
        this->cgx = src.getCenterX();
        this->cgy = src.getCenterY();
        this->endX = src.getEndX();
        this->endY = src.getEndY();
        this->startX = src.getStartX();
        this->startY = src.getStartY();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Note also that if you manually define a copy assignment `operator=()`, you may also want to define a *copy constructor*, probably following the same copy logic implemented in your assignment `operator=()`:

```
Box(const Box& src) :
    cgx   ( src.getCenterX() ),
    cgy   ( src.getCenterY() ),
    endX  ( src.getEndX()    ),
    endY  ( src.getEndY()    ),
    startX( src.getStartX()  ),
    startY( src.getStartY()  )
{}
```

---

**NOTE**

You have a data member `name` in your `Box` class that you are *not* copying. Is this a typo? Are you really sure you don't want to copy it? Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works. With `name`: I forgot to copy it too, so thank you for mentioning it - I added it in my code.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment operator should accept a const object:

```
Box& operator = (const Box& src);
```

Because it will not affect `src` but only `this`.

When you define the copy operator, you should also define the copy constructor. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

An comparison operator should accept a const object and should be const (the function does not change `this`).

```
bool operator == (const Box& src) const;
```

Because it will not affect `src`, nor `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the parameter as const:

```
Box& operator = (const Box &src);
```

Also, you should do the same for the comparison, even though it's not the source of your problem:

```
bool operator == (const Box &src) const;
```

I suspect the right hand side of your assignment or comparison is `const`. Note that this patern is good practice as you are not modifying your parameters.

I've also made the comparison `const` as you won't be modifying `this`.